# .net framework 3.5 login form code not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

i recently developped a pos system in .net framework 4.7.2 the app is working fine and installed in the client machine .
currently i am working on management system for another client in .net framework 3.5 i created the data base  and started coding the login form, i took the existing code from my pos system changed the connection string  everything was going smothly but when i click on the login button nothing happen the next form does not show. here is the code

```
if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter user name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textBox1.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textBox2.Focus();
            return;
        }
        string cs = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=filali;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection myConnection = default(SqlConnection);
        myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlCommand myCommand = default(SqlCommand);

        myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.[login] where [username] = @user and password = @pass", myConnection);

        SqlParameter uName = new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter uPassword = new SqlParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        uName.Value = textBox1.Text;
        uPassword.Value = textBox2.Text;

        myCommand.Parameters.Add(uName);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(uPassword);

        myCommand.Connection.Open();
        try
        {
            

            SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            if (myReader.Read() == true)
            {
                
                    string role = myReader.GetString(3).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(3).ToString());
                    switch (role)
                    {
                        case "a":
                        Console.WriteLine("this is admin "+role);
                        mdiparent1 mdiparent1 = new mdiparent1();
                            this.Hide();
                            mdiparent1.Show();
                     

                            break;
                        case "u":
                            sortiev2 instance = new sortiev2();
                            this.Hide();
                            instance.Show();

                            if (instance.FormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.None)
                                instance.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;

                            instance.BringToFront();

                            if (instance.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
                                instance.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;



                            break;
                    }

                
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
            }

            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                myConnection.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

the sql connection is working because "role" is logged in the console and not empty i don't know why it does not execute the switch statement is there any syntax errors ? is it the fact that i created a project with a diffrent framework?

Comment: You don't need three lines to add a Parameter, just one: `myCommand.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, [Field Size]).Value = textBox1.Text;`. Same for others, e.g., `var myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs);` -- Since you use `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`, declare the DataReader with `using` statement, so it will close the connection when it's closed. -- Put a breakpoint in `string role = myReader.GetString(3).ToString();`, check what you got there then proceed step-by-step to see what happens.

Comment: Add break point to check if `switch` executed and whether the string role is "a" or "u". And you said "took the existing code", did you subscribe to the `click` event of the button?

Comment: @KyleWang i did a ' Console.WriteLine("this is admin "+role)' the switch does not execute i tried all frameworks in projet propreties why is the switch not executing idon't really know

Comment: @Mcyes Did you tried adding breakpoints? Are `if (myReader.Read() == true)` and `Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(3).ToString());` executed? And what is the value of `role` you got?

Comment: @KyleWang thank you for your response yes `Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(3).ToString());` did execute and the value of role is "a" when it gets to the switch it stoped

Comment: @Mcyes It's weird. Could you upload a project which can reproduce the issue, such as via OneDrive? Note: please remove the part that needs to be connected to the database. For example, assign value "a" to `role` directly.

Comment: @KyleWang i uninstalled visual studio 19 and installed 2017 still the same issue. i tried assigning a string value to role ` string role = "a";`and it worked it showed the mdi parent form so i found out where the problem is ,acctually role is not printing "a" it is printing "a         " with spaces any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @KyleWangthe issue was acctually my datasource, that is returning trailing spaces.

    string role = myReader.GetString(3).ToString()

 
was not returning

    a

but

    'a               '

to solve this i simply added `.TrimEnd()`to get rid of the trailing 

istead of this 

    string role = myReader.GetString(3).ToString()

i used this :

    string role = myReader.GetString(3).TrimEnd()

and id worked thanks to everyone who helped !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was acctually my datasource, that is returning trailing spaces.

```
string role = myReader.GetString(3).ToString()
```

was not returning

```
a
```

but

```
'a               '
```

to solve this i simply added `.TrimEnd()`to get rid of the trailing

istead of this

```
string role = myReader.GetString(3).ToString()
```

i used this :

```
string role = myReader.GetString(3).TrimEnd()
```

and id worked thanks to everyone who helped !